# Prevent device from being ejected (Windows 10 Pro)

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, smartcard, safely-remove-hardware

I have a fixed device (5.25 device), a smartcard reader, that is ejectable and appears in "safe removal".
The problem is that if I misclick this smartcard reader while is about to eject a USB memory, the computer locks up, mouse/keyboard wont work, and mouse/keyboard wont even work after a reboot, and the only way to recover, is to go into safe mode with a PS/2 mouse/keyboard, and then uninstall all USB-drivers and then reinstall them again.

Its specifically mentioned in the manual that this smartcard drive should NOT be ejected even if its possible to do so.

The question now is: How can I prevent this from happening? I have tried in regedit to set "Capabilities" flag to 0x2 instead of 0x4, which solves the problem for the session being (it disappears from the safe remove hardware menu), but rebooting, the computer or shutting it down and starting it again, will reset "Capabilities" to 0x4.

Is there any other way to remove the smart card reader from the safe removal menu? Like using Group policy or something? (I don't want to prevent safe removal of USB-drives or other USB devices, just this smartcard reader)

Comment: this worked for me for a hard drive, idk about other devices, but might be a start - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/my-internal-sata-device-appears-in-devices-and/722221d6-d59c-4cf7-803c-8203e6344b93?auth=1

Comment: The problem is that this Controls SATA ports (even "virtual" SATA ports created by USB flash memory), so yes, it only works for disk devices.

Comment: ah, ok - sorry, best I could find :)